# gregoriancalendar getTime keeps returning hour as 12

Tags: java, android

I'm currently writing an android app in which in one fragment, the user enters in a time that they start their morning commute at, via the timepicker contained in a dialogfragment. That gets input into a GregorianCalendar object. When I check the object's toString method in both fragments, the settings I choose are in there, both the hour, minutes, and AM/PM value. My problem comes that when I call the appropriate TextView's set text method, the hour always defaults to 12 every single time, even though in the GregorianCalendar object's toString method, all the values have been passed successfully. For some reason I keep losing specifically the hour when I call getTime(). I'm an entry-level coder, so I'm sure there's something I'm missing but I haven't been able to find the answer in the APIs. I thought maybe getTime() returns default values, but then why the minutes are intact?

The point of this method is to update the mDisplayWorkCommute textview when its setText() is called after receiving an extra, and that's where I'm seeing that the text keeps getting a default hour (12), but still displaying the minute value that was set. I've narrowed it down to something I'm doing wrong here, but there's always the possibility that the issue is somewhere else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void updateText()
{
    if (mUser.mDriveToWorkTime.toString() + mUser.workWeekString() != null)
    {
        Log.i(MAIN_MENU, mUser.mDriveToWorkTime.toString());

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.getDefault());
        mDisplayWorkCommute.setText((CharSequence)(sdf.format(mUser.mDriveToWorkTime.getTime()) +" , " + mUser.workWeekString()));
    }
}
```

edit:

`String` is being cast to `CharSequence` because passing a string to the `TextView`'s `.setText()` seemed to cause Eclipse to keep telling me that I was passing an invalid argument. I just tried it again and it compiled fine and Eclipse didn't panic this time, so that's struck out. mDriveToWorkTime is a GregorianCalendar object that I'm using, and the data that's currently stored in it by the time it's passed to the fragment this is happening in is, according to its `toString()`

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=America/New_York,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=1,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=?,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=45,SECOND=1,MILLISECOND=?,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]

the `Date` object that gets created returns

> Tue Feb 01 00:45:01 EST 1

as its `toString()`. The hour is getting reset to a default every time, but the minute stays intact. This is the XML for mDisplayWorkCommute (it's setting in a `RelativeLayout`):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/userWorkDateTimeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enterWorkDateTimeButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: Please use spaces rather than tabs to format your code when posting into Stack Overflow. Also, why are you casting from `String` to `CharSequence`? Can you show a sample value for `mDriveToWorkTime`? Also note that the result of string concatenation is *never* null, so you might as well take the condition out.

Comment: If you could show the type of `mDriveToWorkTime` and any configuration (e.g. the XML) that would help too.

Comment: I would highly recommend using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: please provide the value of `mUser.mDriveToWorkTime.getTime()` that you are passing. if it's a `Date`, provide the time it uses (it's `String` representation)

Comment: also, I'd advise (while debugging) to use in the `SimpleDateFormat` ZZZZ as well, to see the timezone it uses. In my case, your date format returns correctly for my timezone.

Comment: Edits added to answer questions. Also looking into Joda Time in case I reach an impasse.